# How to keep window on top in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a TCL/TK gui, having some intermediate windows. I keep my main window busy when, intermediate windows are launched.

But sometimes intermediate window goes in background when launching other applications, at this time GUI seems to hang. So objective is to keep window in foreground/background along with main window.

I go for transient window option.

```
wm transient .runner .restGUI
```

This is working fine in windows, but in linux the transient window doesn't show [x] close button. I have to right click on title  bar to close it. Which makes the GUI ineffective.

Any suggestions for that.

Also tested, wm deiconify not working for regular windows in Linux, but worked for transient windows.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to *guarantee* that a window will stay on top; other programs can always intercede and prevent it. But you can provide a really strong *hint* by setting the right [attribute on the window](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9457).

```
# Can use any boolean value here
wm attributes .runner -topmost yes
```

This is a cross-platform attribute (one of the very few that is) provided you are using a sufficiently modern Tk on a sufficiently modern platform. You probably are already doing so.

You should also style the window to look like a transient and so on. The topmost attribute is an independent axis.

For a more extended discussion (much now obsolete) see [the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3014)…

Comment: Always ask: what will happen if an other application will do this, too?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with `grab .runner` which keeps window in top.
But again  that is working in windows only, not in linux.

Want a solution for both platform, as product validation is done on both the platforms

Comment: You might want to edit this into your question as this is not technically an answer, then delete this answer.